# How to make entry / exit actions show up in State Machine diagram

Tags: enterprise-architect, state-machine

I created a **State Machine**, added a **State** from the Toolbar and added an **Entry-Action** via **Features & Properties > Operations** to the State. I'd now like this Entry-Action to show up in the visualization of my state, e.g.:

```
+ entry / someEntryAction(); 
+ exit / someExitAction();
```

like it does for example in the Resource of the State Machine Diagram here: [Sparx Systems: State Machine Diagram](https://www.sparxsystems.eu/resources/project-development-with-uml-and-ea/state-machine-diagram/). I followed the resources on how to add entry /exit actions, but my State stays empty except it's name as a header.

#### This is how my state looks:

[image]

#### This is how I'd like the states to look:

[image: Sparx Systems State Machine Sample Image]

What are the right settings to have the entry / exit actions show up in the visualization of a state?

Comment: Please check whether Operations are made visible in that diagram . Open Diagram Properties- >Elements tab and in show compartment enable operations. and also in feature tab enable visible class members

Comment: In `Show Compartments` two points are checked: `Attributes` and `Operations`. No other element is check. Languange is set to `<none>`.

Comment: In Features-Tab `Visible Class Members` all elements are checked.

Comment: Did you checked Feature and Compartment Visibility of that element or use ( Ctrl + Shift + y) in that element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether operations are visible in that diagram

1. Goto Diagram Properties -> Elements Tab and in **show compartment enable operations.**

   [image]
2. Goto Diagram Properties -> Features Tab and in **Visible class members enable all.**
   [image]
3. Go to Feature and Compartment Visibility of that element **( Ctrl + Shift + y)** and enable all the members under Operation visibility and also please check the custom property of it.
   [image]
4. In the Operations dialog under Behaviour you have the check "Show Behavior in Diagram".

Arshad

Comment: Thanks for the great answer - sadly, even after rechecking twice I still don't see the entry / exit actions...

Comment: Which version of EA are you using ?

Comment: I'm using EA 12.1.1227

Comment: Thanks again - all those settings look correct. I just need to figure out what's misconfigured on my EA...

Comment: Yes better create an  empty EA model and check it

Comment: This is weird - when I now create a **new** State and add an entry / exit action it shows up. The **old** States still do not show the entry / exit actions... looks like AE has a little settings hickup here?! Thanks anyway, I'll mark your answer as the solution, since it kinda solved my problem.

Comment: There is also an setting int the operations dialog in the Behaviour-tab that needs to be the checked: "Show Behavior in Diagram". (from http://www.sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,40063.0.html)

Comment: Yes Missed it. Sorry for that.Updated the answer